# What are the column header names in from historical klines websocket in binance?

Tags: binance

I am retrieving historical data from binance using the 'get_historical_klines' (http://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html#binance.client.Client.get_historical_klines)

I am returned what the documentation is is OHLCV but that doesnt seem to be the case I get 10 numerical column headers from the websocket but can not find any where in the documentation what the 10 column headers are?

Example of websocket sorted into a dataframe.

```
              0           1           2           3           4   \
0  1526397360000  0.00149350  0.00149360  0.00149200  0.00149360   

              5              6           7   8              9           10 11  
0  1535.88000000  1526397419999  2.29395137  30  1477.75000000  2.20716183  0
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Python-Binance API wrapper is not officially from Binance, but it uses the Binance API. The kline/candlestick headers are documented in Binance's [Rest API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data)

Here is the example and column headers provided in that documentation.

```
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
]
```

Comment: moved to https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Comment: What is "Ignore"?

Comment: @CyberPlayerOne In persian we said `Nokhodi`, means something that exist but haven't seen by others. I mean you should take your eyes on it and repeat: "nothing is here, nothing is here,.., yes I'm really sure nothing is here"  `（*ﾟーﾟ）` . anyway I think you can check it [here](https://www.binance.com/es-LA/support/faq/how-to-download-historical-market-data-on-binance-5810ae42176b4770b880ce1f14932262)